# What is this %<s called?

Tags: java, string, format

I have recently come across this following string: "%<s".
I noticed that this has the following effect:

```
String sampleString = "%s, %<s %<s";
String output = String.format(sampleString, "A");
System.out.println(output); // A, A A.
```

I tried to google what this %<s is called, but to no avail. I know from the above code that I just need to input the format string once, and it will replace all instances of %s & %<s.

Just curious what this name is called!

Comment: "A" is repeatedly used for the second and third %. [Relative indexing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%<s` is still a "format specifier", just like `%s`, except that `%<s` has `<` in its "argument index" position. Note that a format specifier in general has a syntax like this:

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

and the it is allowed to use `<` as the `argument_index` part ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)):

> **Argument Index**
>
> [...]
>
> Another way to reference arguments by position is to use the '<'
> ('\u003c') flag, which causes the argument for the previous format
> specifier to be re-used.

The documentation doesn't call the `<` part a special name either, just "the '<' flag".

Answer (score 5):

They are called format specifiers.  Here you are using relative indexing.

From the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

**Relative indexing is used when the format specifier contains a '<'** ('\u003c') flag which causes the argument for the previous format specifier to be re-used. If there is no previous argument, then a MissingFormatArgumentException is thrown.

```
formatter.format("%s %s %<s %<s", "a", "b", "c", "d")
// -> "a b b b"
// "c" and "d" are ignored because they are not referenced
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the code from [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) Class you will find:

Related description from the class documentation:

> Relative indexing is used when the format specifier contains a '<' ('\u003c') flag which causes the argument for the previous format
> specifier to be re-used. If there is no previous argument, then a
> MissingFormatArgumentException is thrown.
> formatter.format("%s %s %<s %<s", "a", "b", "c", "d")
> // -> "a b b b"
> // "c" and "d" are ignored because they are not referenced

**Code reference:**

```
// indexing
static final Flags PREVIOUS = new Flags(1<<8);   // '<'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<` flag is a relative argument index.

Constructed as `%<s`, it allows you to re-use the argument for the previous `%s` format specifier, in this case.

You can read more about it and other formatting flags here: [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)

From the Javadoc:

> Relative indexing is used when the format specifier contains a '<'
> ('\u003c') flag which causes the argument for the previous format
> specifier to be re-used. If there is no previous argument, then a
> MissingFormatArgumentException is thrown.